# Buddhism as a political party?

Tags: modern-world

Would it be advisable to form a political party based on the Dhamma?
This would, of course, not mean that all people would have to become Buddhist, but just let their nation be governed by Buddhist principles.

The current ideologies seems to be either highly confused and clueless, intentionally abusive or just greedy. To benefit the people over the politicians, I was thinking that a Buddhist party could help the world to become more peace and make more sense to peoples lives.

Answer (score 1):

Great idea. I don't know where the story is on the internet but the late Master Nan says in one of his lectures that some Buddha and his disciples, samadhi powers and all, tried to change India.
They failed. People are just too lazy and their karma way too thick to cut through mere skillful means. *You help a person, and you enable their laziness and create a karmic debt for them! You jerk.* **You ignore them and let them suffer, they become motivated and help a million people.**
Every action has an opposite reaction.

Other people can't save you without un-saving you later.
Buddha just can't save you, otherwise he'd have done it. There's something big going on!!
Buddha just can't kill your bad karma or anyone's bad karma.

He can only act as a intermediary and *help* purify that karma because of positive states of mind: shame, renunciation, faith, wisdom, concentration, meditation on the Buddha's positive qualities, etc. Buddha actually does little but act as a meditation object. The true power of mantras, according to Master Nan, can't even be accessed except by those in a deep state of dhyana/jhana/samadhi.

This is the same for confessions in Catholicism. Mother Mary can't do anything!
It was just a skillful means as mentioned in the previous paragraph.

**If the Buddhas could effectively help people through political leadership--it would have already happened. It's because of some sort of karmic binding where people are self-responsible and must change their own fate, that they have not/cannot do it.**

Politics is dirty, people are greedy, corrupt, and self-rationalizing! Even if Buddhism could become a political party--I doubt it stay for long. It would eventually become hijacked, derail, or decay.
The Three Poisons are stacking, moment by moment, millions of times in a day unawares until they cause people to behave in surprisingly evil ways. Countries have their own karma and everyone is contributing to it, it is hard for a small amount of people to purify the whole country's bad karma, especially when they are working against so many suave, manipulative, and cold-blooded murdering politicians.

The only salvation is self-awareness whilst not attaching to anything, not taking anything for self. Who cares about others anyway? Everyone will save themselves, give it a few million eons. All the while you enjoy yourself as a Buddha in Perfect Enlightenment, manifesting a million nirmanakaya bodies helping-beings-throughout-the-universe-through-causes-and-conditions.

Comment: Nothing ventured, nothing gained. Buddhism is more known now and has gained respect throughout the world. Sure there would be people trying to sabotage such a project, but maybe then a form of "peoples quality control"-system could be applied to avoid corruption...

It is not about making people meditate or turn them to be Buddhist. It is only to use the principles and logic of Buddhism to run a nation, so that people may be content. As it is now - we have a corporation controlled Democracy killing people everywhere in the world. 

Maybe now, the world is ready for a new political initiative?

Comment: Well put Peter.
Making people meditate IS the solution though, starting with a mandatory zazen session in all schools. It is the easiest way to enable emotional self-management for our children who are in a hell of propaganda.
As for running a nation, Buddhism doesn't teach how to rule a nation, right?
It teaches how to rule oneself and quiet one's heart.

Comment: We should never force anything. That is what happens now with democracy. A few people deciding how everybody should live life. We can offer meditation as an option, then people choose for themselves. It's like the UN decided to "force peace" which can never lead to peace. We can give the environment, which can lead to peace and hope people would be inspired by it.

To rule a nation, you have to see the people as a person. This body of the person has many parts and each part need to function. It also means that each group has to work with one or more groups to survive. 

Keyword : Freedom

Comment: The Buddha DID advise ruler of Nations on different matters. It is not such a far out idea. It just has to be formulated correctly. 

Meditation is also just a tool - not a complete solution to everything. Practice has to be applied as well.

Comment: And... Of all the silly things we do during the day, I think it is worth spending time on pursuing this idea. Better than playing Xbox all day. hahaha

Comment: haha well anything compared to ultimate social Buddhist evolution is going to look pretty irrelevant.
As for "we should never force anything", I think i mis-explained it. I don't mean we should hold a gun to someone's head and tell them to meditate, but that we should integrate meditation into the learning curriculum and into a point-system so that our ADD and sex-obsessed kids learn to focus and hear their own thoughts..
Anyway, as much as I am with you bro, I don't think that these kind of things can happen... have you ever read the book "The Biggest Secret"? It seems like you might have.

Comment: It could be worth the effort. Nothing ventured, nothing gained... I currently reside in Thailand - I am sure I can find people to support in vote, backup  and financial support from all over SE Asia... If it doesn't work out - at least I will have a cool story to tell the Grandchildren before I eat them...